# set one image in a gallery as primary image

Tags: wordpress, image

I would like to develop an image gallery in wordpress,for that I have crated one custom post type called "Projects" using Types plugin in wp.In  projects post type have one custom field called images of field type gallery. How can I set one of the image in gallery as primary image that would be shown in front end.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create any post type for image gallery. [register a media taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) or install a media category plugin. then create a category "Projects". upload your image and set your category "Projects".

In front-end fetch every image as per category "Projects".